# Rails UJS ajax:complete not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ujs

I have a link that fires off an ajax request using Rails UJS.  The response actually replaces the parent element containing the link.  The ajax:before event fires off as expected, but the ajax:complete event never fires.  I thought this was just a result of the element being replaced.  But just to check, I bound directly to an ajax "complete" callback without using UJS and it works fine.

So my question is why does the "complete" callback work when binding directly to an ajax call but doesn't work when binding through UJS to the "ajax:complete"?

Comment: check your server logs, and watch for the line "processing request as" which should give you a big clue.  alternatively, check the request headers in chrome through the debugger and look at the "accepts".. should be application/javascript.. ensure that your are doing respond_to do |formart| format.js.... not format.json

Comment: I checked and everything is showing js as it should.  Its processing the rendered js just fine, but the ajax:complete just won't fire.

Comment: hi @TomRossi i have the same issue what is the solution please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this jquery-ujs issue:

[Event ajax:complete does not get triggered after form-replacement](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/223)

Comment: Thats it!  Do you understand what they are saying?

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't thinking when I posted my comment earlier (apologies) but now I think I am awake enough to help you :).

Although JQuery supports the script() function, you don't normally fire UJS through Ajax!  Use a regular form_tag with remote:true (which will stick a 'data-remote' tag within your form.  Ajax works with JSON and with UJS, you will be returning pure js

Remember that the action will render to a form usually by the name of app/views/<controller>/<action>.js.erb (or whatever template technology you are currently using)

Remember to have the respond_to block in your controller such as 

`respond_to do |format|
  format.js   #note.. not .json
end`

also ensure that your request headers accept javascript.. 'application/javascript', 'script'

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself.  I am not using a form. I have a simple link_to that is using :remote => true. Alternatively, I am using $.ajax directly and it works fine.